# Extract text from .txt file and save into .csv files with columns and header

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe, nlp

I have approximately 100 text files with clinical notes that consist of 1-2 paragraphs. Each file is named doc_1.txt to doc_179.txt accordingly. I would like to save the text from each file into a .csv file with 2 columns w/ headers (id, text). The  `id` columns are the name of each files.

For example `doc_1` is the record file name and will become the id. The text in `doc_1` will be stored the `text column`. The desired results is below

```
|   id  | text |
|:-----:|:----:|
| doc_1 | abcf |
| doc_2 | efrf |
| doc_3 | gvni |
```

So far I am to just viewed the text and have not determine the best practical way to achieve my results.

Comment: Have you looked into the [csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) available in Python 3? It allows you to read each line of a file into a csv, and you can specify a delimiter.

Comment: @jhelphenstine No, I have not tried csv library. Looking at similar code, I think I would have to append the file name and text.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you would have a list of files.

```
import pandas as pd # remove if already imported

# ...

files_list = ["doc_1.txt", "doc_2.txt", ..., "doc_179.txt"]
```

Create DataFrame with the necessary columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["id", "text"])
```

Iterate through each file to read the text and then save into a csv file

```
for file in files_list:
    with open(file) as f:
        txt = f.read() # to retrieve the text in the file
        file_name = file.split(".")[0] # to remove file type
        df = df.append({"id": file_name, "text": txt}, ignore_index=True) # add row to DataFrame


df.to_csv("result.csv", sep="|", index=False) # export DataFrame into csv file
```

Feel free to change the name of the output csv file (`result.csv`) and the character used for `sep`.

It is strongly advised **not** to use a character that already contained in the text of any of the files. (For example, if any of the text files already contains commas in the text, do not use `,` as the `sep` value.)

Comment: Thank you very much! If I could cast more than one vote, I would.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to update the solution that was provided to me to resolve my problem.

```
import pandas as pd

import glob

txtfiles = []
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    txtfiles.append(file)

files_list = [f for f in glob.glob("*.txt")]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["id", "text"])

for file in files_list:
    with open(file) as f:
        txt = f.read() # to retrieve the text in the file
        file_name = file.split(".")[0] # to remove file type
        df = df.append({"id": file_name, "text": txt}, ignore_index=True)
```